# Combine two RGBA images based on A(transparent) Chanel using NumPy instead of for loop

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have two images with RGBA color type and I want to combine them based on the transparent channel I write the code using exclusive for loop but I want to use the NumPy in order to achieve speed

```
crop = img[y:y+height,x:x+width,:].copy()
for i in range(0,height):
    for j in range(0,width):
        if(crop[i,j,3]  < resized_box[i,j,3]):
            crop[i,j,:] = resized_box[i,j,:]
img[y:y+height,x:x+width,:] = crop
```

Comment: the crop image and the resized_box have the same size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
# NOTE: I'm assuming x, y, width and height are defined somewhere and width, height match resized_box's shape
where_to_overwrite = img[y:y+height,x:x+width,3] < resized_box[:,:,3]
img[y:y+height,x:x+width,:][where_to_overwrite] = resized_box[where_to_overwrite]
```

Basically, first you identify the index of the pixels that need to be overwritten (which, based on yur code, seems to be those where the crops's alpha channel is lower than the `resized_box`'s), then you actually set the values.

I believe the double-indexing in the second is necessary because first you make a view over the crop and then use the computed boolean index to identify the specific pixels in there.